# Regexp convert sql LIMIT syntax to SqlServer TOP syntax

Tags: c#, sql-server, regex, postgresql, regex-greedy

I have some query string written for PostgreSQL and I have to convert them to SqlServer. I'm using C# 6.

In order to convert from LIMIT syntax to TOP syntax I've written the following simple regex:

```
SELECT ([\S\s]*)LIMIT (\d+) -> SELECT TOP $2 $1
```

The complete line code is:

```
return Regex.Replace(query, @"SELECT ([\S\s]*)LIMIT (\d+)", "SELECT TOP $2 $1", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
```

Now, eveything works fine for simple query but it does not work for subquery: the TOP string is put everytime in the super parent query.

Try for example the following query:

```
SELECT b3.aaa,
       b3.count
FROM
(
    SELECT CONCAT(b.foo / 100.0, '-', (b.foo + 10) / 100.0) AS aaa,
                      COUNT(b.foo) AS count
    FROM
    (
        SELECT b2.foo - (b2.foo % 10) AS foo
        FROM
        (
            SELECT CAST(b.foo * 100 AS INT) AS foo
            FROM eee b
                 INNER JOIN bar f ON b.bar_id = f.id
            WHERE b.foo < 1
                  AND f.nome = 'aaa'
        ) b2
    ) b
    GROUP BY b.foo
    ORDER BY b.foo
    LIMIT 10
)
```

it is converted to:

```
SELECT TOP 10 b3.aaa,
       b3.count
FROM
(
    SELECT CONCAT(b.foo / 100.0, '-', (b.foo + 10) / 100.0) AS aaa,
                      COUNT(b.foo) AS count
    FROM
    (
        SELECT b2.foo - (b2.foo % 10) AS foo
        FROM
        (
            SELECT CAST(b.foo * 100 AS INT) AS foo
            FROM eee b
                 INNER JOIN bar f ON b.bar_id = f.id
            WHERE b.foo < 1
                  AND f.nome = 'aaa'
        ) b2
    ) b
    GROUP BY b.foo
    ORDER BY b.foo
)
```

while I'd like to have

```
SELECT b3.aaa,
       b3.count
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 10 CONCAT(b.foo / 100.0, '-', (b.foo + 10) / 100.0) AS aaa,
                      COUNT(b.foo) AS count
    FROM
    (
        SELECT b2.foo - (b2.foo % 10) AS foo
        FROM
        (
            SELECT CAST(b.foo * 100 AS INT) AS foo
            FROM eee b
                 INNER JOIN bar f ON b.bar_id = f.id
            WHERE b.foo < 1
                  AND f.nome = 'aaa'
        ) b2
    ) b
    GROUP BY b.foo
    ORDER BY b.foo
)
```

How should I write the regex I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works okay with some changes I made to handle quoted parens:

```
var pattern = @"SELECT ((?:[^'()]|(?>'[^']+')|(?<open>\()|(?<-open>\)))+(?(open)(?!)))LIMIT (\d+)";

query = Regex.Replace(query, pattern, "SELECT TOP $2 $1");
```

Comment: I could not test your regexp because it has a pattern error, could you please fix it ? Thanks

Comment: I copied and pasted it in and it executes fine.

Comment: Sorry I had pattern error testing on reg101 website, my fault. I tested it and it works fine, many thanks !